# Spring Security By Example

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to learn spring security. I have checked the spring security tutorial. However I want to work on working examples. I couldn't open as a project Spring tutorial sample at Intellij IDEA. Is there any resources that explains spring security and **I can download the sample**?

**PS 1:** I need just a sample which makes login logout process and can not show a page without authorization and authentication, **just a simple example to open as a project** to examine and improve.

**PS 2:** Where is that spring-security-samples-tutorial-' source code? Why http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html says that start from here if I will not able to see the source code?

**PS 3:** An example that so simple no need to connect to database, can read from an xml file as spring security supported.

Comment: I was looking for the same. The best I could find is this https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/tree/master/samples/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you didn't include a link, so I can't know for sure, but did you try creating a *new* project based off the source of the example?

You can only open an existing project with 'open project'

Comment: I downloaded the Spring Security and inside of dist folder there is a war -> spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.0.5.RELEASE.war I extracted it into a folder but can't open as a project, it is just folders and files?

Comment: you need to get the source.  The war probably only contains executables.

Answer (score 0):

Trace this project.

http://code.google.com/p/facility-booking/source/checkout

[spring-security.xml](http://code.google.com/p/facility-booking/source/browse/trunk/FacilityBooking/WebContent/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml) : Note that a bean with name , *userService* . The bean will be processed when the user login.

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

[UserServiceImpl.java](http://code.google.com/p/facility-booking/source/browse/trunk/FacilityBooking/src/com/iclub/service/impl/UserServiceImpl.java) : User Service bean implementation. The code is self-explanatory.

And this is frontend jsp for login [login.jsp](http://code.google.com/p/facility-booking/source/browse/trunk/FacilityBooking/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest following path to learn spring security purely from the guide of spring

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html

At this link you would find path suggested by spring to learn spring security.

You should start developing spring security from here
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html
A basic example for spring security.
This page also suggests a link to download source and samples for spring security. 
You would build the downloaded source samples and use apache tomcat to run the compiled samples.