# spring servlet filter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am trying to implement servlet filter for spring to implement application access control based on user role can you people recommend me some tutorial for that since I am new in spring mvc.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials.
Check this http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html ,
this [Looking for a Simple Spring security example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899518/looking-for-a-simple-spring-security-example)
and this [Spring Security By Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319896/spring-security-by-example)